# Unhide all the cells (including empty columns and rows) of a worksheet

Tags: excel, ms-office, office-js

I want to unhide all the cells of a worksheet. I try the following code:

```
function unhideSheet (sheetName) {
    return Excel.run(function (ctx) {
        var sheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getItem(sheetNames[i]);
        sheet.visibility = "Visible";
        sheet.getUsedRange().columnHidden = false;
        sheet.getUsedRange().rowHidden = false;
        return ctx.sync();
    });
}
```

The problem is `getUsedRange` does not cover the empty columns or rows that are hidden. As a consequence, the function does not unhide these hidden empty columns or rows.

Does anyone know if it is possible to **get the range for the entire worksheet**, so that we could unhide everything?

**Edit 1:**
I have calculated that the number of rows in a worksheet is `1048576` (Excel Online). What is odd is that `sheet.getRange("1:20").rowHidden = false` works well, whereas `sheet.getRange("1:1048576").rowHidden = false` raises an error `This operation is not permitted for the current object`. Is it because the range is too big?

**I realise that `sheet.getRange("1:1048575").rowHidden = false` works**.

Comment: w.get_Range("a1").EntireRow.EntireColumn?

Comment: I tried `var r = sheet.getRange("A1").getEntireColumn().getEntireRow()`, but got an error for `r.rowHidden = false`: `This operation is not permitted for the current object`.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean...

Comment: I see, it is the row limit of Excel http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-excel/why-does-an-excel-spreadsheet-end-at-1048576-and/0007c3c4-0785-45a4-ad63-78b930773a5e?auth=1 It ends on 1048575 or 1048576 depending whether you index from 0 or 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the entire range of the sheet, use sheet.getRange(), just like this, with no arguments specified.  Does that work?

Comment: `sheet.getRange()` does return the entire range of the sheet. But `sheet.getRange().rowHidden = false` raises an error: `This operation is not permitted for the current object`. I guess the reason is the same as `sheet.getRange("1:1048576").rowHidden = false`...

Comment: I see.  In that case, it sounds like a bug.  Let me file it with the team.

Comment: OK... For your information, the same error raises if an array covers all the columns (ie., from `1` to `16384`), whereas from `1` to `16383` works... These tests were undertaken under Excel Online...